# Generic repository Get() IEnumerable to Async

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

This is my first Asynchronous EF attempt :)

I am having a generic entity framework repository and I want to make it async.

The original code is:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
    return query.ToList();
}
```

I trnsfor it as:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal Context context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    } 

    public virtual Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get()
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
        return query.ToListAsync();
    } 
}
```

However, I have compile error, cannot convert type System.threading.Tasks.Task> to return type Tasks.Task>

The ToListAsync() method retrieve a list and I am expecting an Task>, my oringinal IEnumerable results is using elsewhere to populate selectbox

```
_xxx.Get().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ps_id.ToString(),
                Text = x.ps_label
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Text);
```

Can you point me out what need to be done to do it correctly

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task<T>` is invariant because it's a class. It makes more sense to return a list since you're going through the work of making it that way anyway.

```
public virtual Task<List<TEntity>> Get()
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
    return query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hi, finallly I did that way and transform the other codes to reflect that change. Thanks Shoe